# How to Export Colors in Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, color

How do I export color models in Blender? I'm trying to color them but they come out in gray.

Comment: Try .fbx it should work

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541